# Alternate ways to express Function("return this")

Tags: javascript, node.js, npx, esbuild

I'm working with some esbuild-generated code, and my linter is warning me about an `eval()` usage through the `Function` constructor.

Here's the relevant line:

```js
var require_root = __commonJS({
  "../node_modules/lodash/_root.js"(exports2, module2) {
    var freeGlobal = require_freeGlobal();
    var freeSelf = typeof self == "object" && self && self.Object === Object && self;
    var root = freeGlobal || freeSelf || Function("return this")(); // <========= This line!
    module2.exports = root;
  }
});
```

How else can I express this? I've tried using lambdas, but my primitive JS knowledge is failing me.

Comment: 1. Why are you linting generated code? 2. Why is `Function("return this")()` needed anyway? Isn't that just `global`?

Comment: why don't you simply tell your linter to ignore that line? I do it, not often, but it happens when you know what you're doing.

Comment: @VLAZ in a Node.js environment, it would indeed return `global`. In a browser context, it would return `window`. Modern environments have the global variable [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) that refers to either `global` or `window`.

Comment: @RickN the question is tagged with Node.js hence my own query. Because I don't know *why* is `Function("return this")()` needed or used here.

Comment: @VLAZ  It looks like lodash code, that works Browser / Node, but yes, why is the OP even linting this.. ??

Comment: I'm working in an evironment where this particular linter can't be ignored (it's QuickJS). It does support ECMA 262 so I'll try swapping in the globalThis variable! Thanks!